# Why do browsers ignore content-disposition headers for file names sometimes?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, http-headers, google-cloud-storage

The Next.Js/React application I'm working on utilizes Firebase's cloud storage to store .doc/.docx/.pdf files. I want to be able to dynamically change the suggested file name in the browser document viewer on download, however I can only get it to work sometimes. Since I want to keep the original file name the same, I cannot permanently change the metadata in cloud storage either.

I have found that requesting a signed url from cloud storage and adding a responseDisposition property only works if the original file name doesn't include a '.pdf' or '.docx' in the title.

Here is my server handler code that requests the signed url and sends it back to the client:

```
const {firebaseInit} = require('../../firebase-admin-init');
const fetchResumeLink = async (req,res) => {
  const {documentPath, dynamicName} = req.body;
    const bucket = firebaseInit.storage().bucket();
    const file = bucket.file(documentPath);
    const today = new Date();
    const tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
    const config = {
      action: 'read',
      responseDisposition: `attachment; filename=Resume_for_${dynamicName}.pdf`,
      expires: tomorrow
    }

    file.getSignedUrl(config, (err, url) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
      } else {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
        res.status(200).send(url);
      }
  });
}
```

This method only works in Chrome if the original file is contained at a storage path like /bucket/folder/obj but if it is at /bucket/folder/obj.pdf it doesn't seem to work anymore. On Mozilla I ran across an instance where the tab displayed the correct file name but when prompted to download the file the original file name was the original one.

Does anyone know why this happens? Is there anyway to get the browser document readers to not ignore the content-disposition headers?

Also open to any other methods to dynamically generate a file's saved name.

Answer (score 0):

If a ContentDisposition header is set on the object, it overrides the response-content-disposition query parameter.

So my guess is you're using a library or tool that sets the ContentDisposition on the metadata when you upload objects with certain extensions (like PDF) known to need non-inline display.